# Log4j2 not logging to graylog server properly

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

Right now I am trying use log4j2 to log everything that has a level of I**NFO or higher** (WARN, ERROR, AND FATAL) to my **server** and anything that has a level of **INFO** to my **console**. I am able to log things to my console, however, I am having an issue logging the correct levels to the server properly.

Here is what I have tried so far:

Java

```
import java.time.Instant;

import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class App {
    private static final Logger log4j = LogManager.getLogger(App.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String log4jConfPath = "src/main/resources/log4j2.xml";
            PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jConfPath);
            log4j.info("this is a testmessage " + Instant.now().toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="trace" packages="org.graylog2.log4j2">

    <Properties>
        <Property name="default_pattern">%d{MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss} %5p %c{1} - %m%n
        </Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${default_pattern}" />
        </Console>
        <GELF name="gelfAppender" server="graylog.x.something.com"
            hostName="some.host" port="12201">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
            <KeyValuePair key="extractStacktrace" value="true" />
            <KeyValuePair key="addExtendedInformation" value="true" />
            <KeyValuePair key="facility" value="gelf-java" />
            <KeyValuePair key="environment" value="TEST" />
            <KeyValuePair key="application" value="MyApp" />
            <KeyValuePair key="additionalFields" value="{'environment': 'TEST', 'application': 'MyAPP'}" />
        </GELF>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="gelfAppender" />
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
        </Root>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="gelfAppender" />
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />

        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The above code does not output what I want, which is to have **INFO** level output to the **console** and **INFO Levels and up** output to the **server**.

Instead, I am able to output: EVERYTHING (Trace) to console and INFO to the server.

I have messed around with the XML file a little bit and I noticed that when I change

```
status="trace"
```

to

```
status="off"
```

it logs only INFO to the console, but nothing to the server.

Lastly, and probably the most odd  thing of all, if I remove

```
Instant.now().toString()
```

from my print statement, then nothing will be logged to the server, regardless of the status (if it's TRACE or OFF), but it still logs to the console.
I thought it had something to do with the pattern layout of my GELF appender, so I changed

```
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
```

to

```
<PatternLayout pattern="${default_pattern}" />
```

but that did not change the output...

Here are my current dependencies:

[image]

In short, I just want to log levels of INFO to my console and levels of INFO or higher to my server.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26108045/how-to-log-only-one-level-with-log4j2) tells you how to set up Log4j2 so that INFO and only INFO log messages go to the console.  Also, I'm not sure why you have two `<Root>` elements in `<Loggers>`: as I understand it there should only be one, so try removing `<Root level="error">` and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the link.I removed the extra ROOT element and I added the threshold filters, but still no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you seem to have figured out you should use the threshold filter to filter messages of level `WARN` and up from the console appender.

The correct way to specify different levels for different appenders is to specify it on the `<Appender>` element like this:

```
<Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
        <Appender ref="console"/>
        <Appender ref="file" level="info"/>
    </Root>
</Logger>
```

As to solving your problem, here's a simple example program and configuration that outputs `INFO` level messages to console, all log messages to *everything.log* and `INFO` and up to *infoAndUp.log*.

*LogTest.java*:

```
public class LogTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

        log.trace("This is a trace message");
        log.debug("This is a debug message");
        log.info("This is an info message");
        log.warn("This is a warning message");
        log.error("This is an error message");
        log.fatal("This is a fatal message");
    }
}
```

*log4j2.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
            <Filters>
                <!-- Exclude messages logged above INFO -->
                <ThresholdFilter level="WARN" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            </Filters>
        </Console>
        <File name="everything" fileName="everything.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
        <File name="infoAndUp" fileName="infoAndUp.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="console" level="info"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="everything" />
            <AppenderRef ref="infoAndUp" level="info"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**Results**

*Console output*:

```
09:29:35.331 [main] INFO  LogTest - This is an info message
```

*everything.log*:

```
09:29:35.330 [main] TRACE LogTest - This is a trace message
09:29:35.331 [main] DEBUG LogTest - This is a debug message
09:29:35.331 [main] INFO  LogTest - This is an info message
09:29:35.332 [main] WARN  LogTest - This is a warning message
09:29:35.332 [main] ERROR LogTest - This is an error message
09:29:35.332 [main] FATAL LogTest - This is a fatal message
```

*infoAndUp.log*:

```
09:29:35.331 [main] INFO  LogTest - This is an info message
09:29:35.332 [main] WARN  LogTest - This is a warning message
09:29:35.332 [main] ERROR LogTest - This is an error message
09:29:35.332 [main] FATAL LogTest - This is a fatal message
```

You should be able to fix your own config using this as a base.

Comment: Cool thank you, it works! I know you answered my question, but I have one last question: how come when I add my GELF appender to the above code everything works fine, but if I remove the two File appenders and their corresponding loggers, nothing gets logs to my GELF appender?

Comment: That sounds pretty weird and it's hard to say without actually seeing your config. Maybe you can open up a new question seeing as this one was solved.

Comment: I agree, it makes no sense to me at all, since the File appender and logger should have nothing to do with anything else but logging to only that file. I have created the new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315123/log4j2-does-not-log-to-server-after-removing-file-appender